# React state returns undefined when passed as object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want my id to be increased every time this function is executed,but when I console the object id returns undefined

```
    let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const addNote = (text) => {
                const date = new Date();
                const newNote = {
                    id: setCount(count++),
                    text: text,
                    date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
                };
                const newNotes = [...notes, newNote];
                setNotes(newNotes);
                console.log(newNotes)
            };
```

**Component**

```
<NotesList notes={notes}
           handleAddNote={addNote}
           handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
/>
```

Comment: Instead of using `setCount(count++)`, do `setCount(count+1)`. Plus you should not expect `setCount` to return anything, and if it does, it likely will not be the updated value.

Comment: I guess you meant id: count+1 ...

Comment: setCount should not be the id value, separate the setCount and use the same value you pass to setCount as your id

Comment: setCount(count++)
 id: count++,

Comment: `count++` is 'post increment'.  The value of count is passed, and then incremented, thus there is no change in value going to `setCount`.  Regardless, as others hve said, you're using `setCount` wrong.

Answer (score 0):

set state does not return anything, So initialising to ID is wrong. Instead you can assign your id like this

```
const newNote = {
                id: count+1,
                text: text,
                date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
            };
setCount(count+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `count` state.

Instead try `useState` updater function like this:

```
const addNote = (text) => {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
        const prevId = prevNotes[notes.length - 1].id;
        const date = new Date();
        const newNote = {
          id: prevId + 1,
          text: text,
          date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
        };
        
        return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
};
```